# How do I move the first four elements of an arraylist into another arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Thanks for all your help, I have managed to get it working with the help of the answers provided.

This is my main class:

```
import data.Deck;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        Deck getdeck = new Deck();
        deck = getdeck.get32Cards();

        for (Card info : deck) {
            System.out.println(info); //this just prints all the 
        }        
    }

}
```

This is my card class:
    package business;

```
public class Card {

    public enum Suit{SPADES, CLUBS, HEARTS, DIAMONDS};
    public enum Rank{JACK, KING, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, ACE, QUEEN}

private Suit suit;
private Rank rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
    }
}
```

This is my deck class:

```
package data;

import business.Hand;
import business.Card;
import business.Card.Rank;
import business.Card.Suit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public ArrayList<Card> get32Cards() {

        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.QUEEN));

        Collections.shuffle(deck); //this shuffles the deck

        return deck;
    }
```

I also have a Hand class and a Player class. I intend for two players to each have an instance of a hand. I'm not sure how to remove the first four cards of the 'deck' arraylist, and insert it into another arraylist. Also i don't know which class to write the code. Please advise.

Comment: Your Dealer or Game class would hold the code. Simply call remove on one ArrayList and pass the item obtained to the other by calling `add(...)`. e.g., `handList.add(deckList.remove(0));` Or better call the methods of hand and deck. I'm a bit surprised that you've asked this without first trying something.

Comment: Here are the doc-files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html. Just take a look, which method might suit best for this :-). And next time, please try something and tell, where you are stuck. SO is not an assignment dump.

Comment: I have tried stuff, for example:public boolean giveFourCards(Card c) {
        for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            if (deck.contains(c)) {
                deck.remove(c);
                Hand1.add(c);
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
        return false;    
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create another ArrayList `newArraLIst` like this:

```
   ArrayList<Card> newArraLIst = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

And use for loop to `remove()` first `four` elemets and to `add()` them to new ArrayList like this:

```
    if(deck.size() >= 4){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        newArraLIst.add(deck.remove(i));
      }        
    }
```

Comment: this actually worked, thanks, but i also wanted to remove the element from the original deck arraylist...any thoughts? i know i have to use .remove()

Comment: you can use remove() method

Comment: if i replace the .get() method with a .remove() method, will that work?

Comment: Sure you can use like this .add(deck.remove(i));

Comment: As I said before, i have a hand and a player class. I was wondering, i have two players, each have a hand, and each hand takes four cards from the deck. So we sorted out how to take four cards from the deck, but how would i implement it so that my main class makes two instances of player, where each player makes an instance of a hand, which the hands take the cards from the deck class.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for your code. First of all, adding those cards into deck looks a bit ugly, i would suggest doing something like this:

```
for (Rank rank : Rank.values()){
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()){
            deck.add(new Card(suit, rank);
        }
    }
```

Also, your deck should be a Stack of cards and a hand can be an ArrayList of cards. When u deal your cards from your deck, it should look like this:

```
public static final int HAND_SIZE = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < HAND_SIZE; i++){
    for (Player player : game.getPlayers()){
         player.getHand().add(deck.pop());
    }
}
```

This piece of code deals 4 cards from the deck to each player in the game.
deck.pop() removes last card in the stack and returns it. This way you add a card in a player's hand and remove it from the deck in one line of code.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use a [Stack](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_stack_class.htm) instead of an ArrayList for your deck it makes much more sense. Then you can use pop() method to get and remove the top card at the same time.
However you can use the following n times to keep moving the first element of deck to the start of hand. Replace n with 4 in your case.

```
   ArrayList<Integer> hand = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        hand.add(0, deck.get(0));
                deck.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: so would all i have to do is change the word 'ArrayList' to 'Stack' in order to use that code?

Comment: Maybe it is more clear now. The code is for ArrayLists. Stack would have been a better choice to begin with depending on what else you are going to do.